# How to bubble up errors on docker containers to jenkins in host machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, error-handling

I need to know how to  bubble up / handle errors on docker containers to a jenkins in the host machine, what is the best approach?

I can do it only using docker or i need use docker-compose?

How I can tell to docker to throw a failed exit code if the code running inside of it fail?

Example:

I want to run in jenkins a docker image that run a script with nodeJs.
If this script fail with exit code 1 I need that Jenkins fail the build.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to host an app on the container using Jenkins? By default if any jobs failed with exit code Jenkins will handle and show build fail.

Comment: But if the code inside docker container fail how I can tell to docker to throw a failed exit code?

Comment: What is the docker command you are using in your Jenkins job to run the nodeJS script? What happens when you run that command locally? If it succeeds, you should expect `echo $?` to output `0`. If it fails, you should expect something non-zero. If that is the case, the same will hold when you run the command in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi with the info about the exit codes in docker and CMD command. I was able to throw up all the errors inside of more than one docker container to jenkins using set -e in a bash script starting my docker containers.
If any container fails with a non zero exit code the script stop the current execution and the exit code is catched by jenkins instead to follow with the next docker container execution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar situation here. I created an Execute Shell at Jenkins Build step and put the following script:

```
docker exec ${CONTAINER_NAME}

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   docker stop ${CONTAINER_NAME}
   exit 0 # success
else
   docker stop ${CONTAINER_NAME}
   exit 1 # fail
```

"**$?**" reads the exit status of the last command executed. After a function returns, "**$?**" gives the exit status of the last command executed in the function. This is Bash's way of giving functions a "return value."

Source: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html