# Can't seem to trigger "failure" event in post build action for Jenkins Pipeline with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently working on a quite simple pipeline script to run a node.js script inside a docker image.

My problem is that it seem that even if my scripts ends up with an error inside the container, the pipeline configuration considers that the stage is a success.

From what i've found on the internet for now, it seems that Jenkins uses the exit code of the docker process terminating the container and not the exit code of the script that i've runned in the container, so I always get a 0 exit code, and my post script "failure" is not executed.

Anyone knows how I can get the exit code from inside the container ?

Also, I would like to keep the syntax of the agent as it is, to avoid having to manually type the docker run command in the stage, because I have a lot of environment variables to inject in the container.

So here is a simplified version of my Jenkinsfile.
The `dostuff.js` fails, but Jenkins still tries to archive the artifacts

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:10-alpine' }
    }

    environment {
        SOME_VAR = "some value"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Prepare to do stuff') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm i'
            }
        }

        stage('Do stuff') {
            steps {
                sh './dostuff.js'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.stuf.json'
            echo 'Sending artifact to mailing list'
            emailext attachmentsPattern: '*.stuf.json', body: '', subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", to: 'me@me.com'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Sending failure notifiation'
            emailext attachLog: true, body: '', subject: "Build failed in Jenkins: ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", to: 'not-me@me.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920772/how-to-bubble-up-errors-on-docker-containers-to-jenkins-in-host-machine

Answer (score 0):

Usually, errors are triggered using an exit code != 0

Pretty much all languages have it.

In JS `process.exit(42)`